# how big is SAN and is it feasible to use it in home

Tags: hard-drive, storage, san

I have seen [this add](http://www.gumtree.com.au/s-ad/sydney-region/other-electronics-computers/netapp-san-50tb-storage-array/1043723691) for SAN and its looks cheap for 50TB storage.

But i am not sure

1. How big will that be. i mean can it be fit on my computer desk
2. Can i sue with my normal desktop
3. Is it will be very high power intensive for home user

Can anyone please give throw some light on SAN

Answer (score 1):

This is server grade hardware. It will run loud and hot. This isn't like a normal desktop system. You will want to measure and ask to see if it will fit where you want it.

Yes, you can use it with your normal desktop, but it is not a simple plug and play USB drive.